# Нестандартный синтаксис JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, синтаксис

Часто вижу в коде что-то типа `условие ? действие1 : действие2` или `$имяОбъекта` или даже `var i=function(){$}` и всякое такое. Что это за синтаксис и где про него можно прочитать про это и про то, как как создавать библиотеки типа `jQuery`?

Comment: ``условие ? действие1 : действие2`` 

Эквивалентно:

``if( условие ) { действие1 } else { действие2 }``

Comment: @Spectre, не совсем так. Скорее `(function(){if(условие){return действие1;}else{return действие2;}})();` - с возвращением результата действий.

Comment: не спорю, но для новичка будет более понятным

Comment: И, дабы автор правильно понял, такие особенности присущи всему семейству языков ECMAScript, не только JS "такой особенный"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошая книга = Бер Бибо, Иегуда Кац "jQuery. Подробное руководство по продвинутому JavaScript". Там начиная с азов и заканчивая довольно профессиональными вещами

Comment: Лучше начинать с основ "Learning JavaScript", потом "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide", а потом уж про jQuery...

Comment: Хорошая книга для старта изучения JavaScript - <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/047022780X?ie=UTF8&amp;tag=nczonline-20&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;camp=1789&amp;creative=390957&amp;creativeASIN=047022780X">Professional JavaScript for Web Developers (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)</a> Николаса Закаса, она хоть и на английском только доступна, но вполне доступно и понятно написана. Флэнаган всё же посложнее, хотя книга безусловно - классика по JavaScript. 
А по jQuery - конечно, Бибо и Кац.

Comment: человеку непонятна запись `var i=function(){$}` ему еще рано JQuery...

Comment: А я порочитал Beginning Java Script Paul Wilton Jeremy McPeak и основы знаю мне надо дальше изучать!

Comment: ps Есть книга про эти ваши  var i=function(){$} и прочие заумности?

Comment: Это не наши заумности а заумности javascript... Тут на самом деле вы или понимаете как в javascript устроены функции или нет :)

Answer (score 0):

Стоян Стефанов: JavaScript. Шаблоны. (JavaScript Patterns.) ИМХО одна из лучших по js

Answer (score 0):

У этого ОПЕРАТОРА есть своё название - ТЕРНАРНЫЙ ОПЕРАТОР.

```
if (условие) { 
   //операторы
} else { 
   //операторы
}
```

И это никакой не стандарт. Такой оператор есть в C#, С++, С, Java и т.д. Короче, во всех "салидных" языках.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то тернарный оператор это $variable = condition ? expressionl  -. expression2, а то что выше - это условный оператор

Comment: я расписал как работает тернарный оператор